# How many wifi streams does the Macbook Pro support?

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro

I'm referring to the Macbook Pro Retina 15-inch (2013) model. I read that it supports three streams, and that it supports both 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz.

The question is: does it support three streams on both 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz, for a total of 6 streams? If not, how many streams does it support at 2.4Ghz, and how many at 5Ghz?

I'm looking at buying a router, so I want to make sure that the router supports as many streams at each frequency as the Macbook does. Thanks.

Comment: it would be limited by your WiFi bandwidth and your Mac. And by stream you mean what exactly?

Comment: MIMO -- the Mac has multiple wifi antennas that talk to multiple antennas on the router for increased performance. See http://mobile.pcmag.com/?origref=#!/article/52670ed9cb0071dbf102f215-inside-the-new-ipad-macbook-wi-fi-specs-and-what-s-mimo